# Matplotlib stacked barplots with individual edgecolors similar to pgfplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some stacked barplots which could look like this

[image]

But I'd really like edgecolors that follow the rest of the colors, e.g. like pgfplots
[image]

Is this possible (within reason) in Matplotlib?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

test1 = np.array([51, 13.8, 15.5, np.NaN])
test2 = np.array([40.3, 30.4, 13.8, 15.5])

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(test1 = test1,
                       test2 = test2),
                  columns = ["test1","test2"]).T

ax = df.plot.barh(stacked = True, cmap = "coolwarm", edgecolor = "black", lw = 1, width = 0.8, figsize = (6,4))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the edges of the bar are black because you have set `edgecolor = "black"` in the call to `df.plot.barh`. Removing this means that there will be no edgecolor. You will need to set the edgecolor of each bar to that of the bars facecolor

You can do this by iterating through the rectangle patches (obtained using `ax.patches`) and setting the edgecolor to the facecolor using [`get_facecolor()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.get_facecolor) and [`set_edgecolor()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_edgecolor).

```
test1 = np.array([51, 13.8, 15.5, np.NaN])
test2 = np.array([40.3, 30.4, 13.8, 15.5])

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(test1 = test1,
                       test2 = test2),
                  columns = ["test1","test2"]).T

ax = df.plot.barh(stacked = True, cmap = "coolwarm", lw = 1.5, width = 0.8, figsize = (6,4))

for rect in ax.patches:
    facecolor = list(rect.get_facecolor())
    rect.set_edgecolor(facecolor)

    facecolor[-1] = 0.5  # reduce alpha value of facecolor, but not of edgecolor
    rect.set_facecolor(facecolor)

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]